# Could an Internet-connected IP network be NOT registered to a Regional internet Registery (RIR) or any local network registery?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ip

Currently I am in the process of learning the whole DNS thing. I'm learning from the O'Reilly book "[DNS and BIND](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do)".

In section 3.4.2 the author states that in order for a domain name registrar to be able to delegate a subdomain to a nameserver, that nameserver must be on a registered internet-connected IP network (registered by a network registry). And also, he states the need to double check whether the ISP network, on which the nameserver resides is registered.

*The question is*: Is it possible for the ISP's network to not be registered by an RIR (or any local network regisery for that matter), because it doesn't make sense to me. I mean, I think that any "Internet-connected" network must be registered by the authority that delegated the IP range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "Internet-Connected" could be a sticking point.

And NAT would probably be the glue.

It's not unheard of for networks to use *bogon* space for their own internal purposes (think [Hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29)). But the rule basically states that to use an IP as a nameserver, everyone has to be able to get to it. If the predicate is true then that's really the bit you care about. The details are more of a technical explanation of the steps that need to be in place.

The details are probably of greater interest to someone who is currently in the process of setting up a large-scale network and therefore needs to know what happens before what.

Comment: I agree, but does the rule of 'everyone has to be able to get to it' apply for a nameserver that is hosted on a dynamic IP (pc at home with adsl connection) with a dynamic DNS service like freedns.afraid.org for updating the DNS records dynamically ? I just need to experiment at home.

Comment: DNS servers (practically by definition) need to be on a static IP. The IP address of the DNS server goes into the global registry. If you want to run a DNS server off a dynamic IP, then delegate a subdomain to your dns server instead.

Comment: Thanks for your short-but-precise answers. You saved me a lot of hassles with your last recommendation on namerserver on a dynamic IP.

Comment: in the post ipv4 world there may not even be an RIR to register with.  Consider prop 103 http://www.apnic.net/policy/proposals/prop-103.  you can read one commentary here http://www.circleid.com/posts/20120720_rirs_in_post_ipv4_world_is_end_of_ip_address_policy_making_nigh/

Comment: Good informing post. RIR would probably be down, but I still think there should be at least some form of authority for address block distribution and registration.